# Creating a user valid for a given time period?

Tags: ubuntu, users, useradd

I wan to create a user on Ubuntu valid for 10 min. How can I do that if it's possible?

Comment: What actual operating system? Is this really Unix or Linux? Which Unix? Which Linux?

Comment: @terdon i'm using Ubuntu

Comment: Related: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109148/how-to-control-the-time-that-users-spend-on as well as this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1181/lock-some-accounts-during-some-time-periods/1186#1186

Comment: @slm it's not that

Comment: Sure you can, create the account and then set a crontab entry that will run `pw lock <user>` 10 min. later.

Answer (score 1):

To add a new user with an expiration date, do:

```
useradd -e 2014-02-03 foobar
```

That will create a user called `foobar` who will only be valid until the 3d of February 2014. From `man useradd`:

```
   -e, --expiredate EXPIRE_DATE
       The date on which the user account will be disabled. The date is
       specified in the format YYYY-MM-DD.
```

I don't think it is possible to give smaller intervals than "tomorrow" however. A possible workaround would be to create a normal user and then delete that user in ten minutes:

```
adduser foobar && sleep 600 && deluser foobar
```

---

#### NOTE:

`adduser` is a front end to `useradd`. In general, on Debian based systems, `adduser` is to be preferred since it automates all sorts of things like creating a user directory etc. The `useradd` command will not do this by default so you should read it's `man` page to learn how it works and what options you should use.

Comment: +1 Flagged it as a dup but UV'd your A since it's good stuff.

Comment: @slm thanks :). I'm in the process of editing your linked A to add the tricks from this thread about dealing with minutes and I'll vote to close this as a dupe as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the user with `useradd` and then schedule a `usermod --lock` command with `at`, e.g.:

```
# echo usermod --lock juser | at now + 10 minutes
```

Depending on your requirements you may want to verify what account invalidation procedure you need to execute via `at`.

Note that disabling an account [is not trivial](http://utcc.utoronto.ca/~cks/space/blog/sysadmin/DisablingAccountChallenge).

Even when deleting it - that does not necessarily mean that her current login session and all running processes are immediately terminated.

Comment: @terdon, deleting the user may be fine as well - I just picked locking because the OP talked about making it **valid** for 10 minutes.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I see why you use lock and not delete.

Comment: if `at` is not installed then we can use `( sleep 10m && usermod --lock foobar & )` isn't it?